# threadsafety vs Iterator validity

Tags: c++, multithreading, iterator, race-condition, stdmap

I have two threads:

- Thread A inserting into an `std::map`
- Thread B removing from  an `std::map`

Since `std::map::erase` and `std::map::insert` keep all iterators of the map valid, I don't seem to understand how a race condition could occur in this scenario.

Comment: There may be internal state of the map that gets messed up doing both calls at the same time.  `size` comes to mind.

Comment: Since only const functions in the latest c++ standard are required to be thread safe, and std::map is not required to be thread safe, why would you not expect a race condition when calling non-const functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are saying the right thing. I will combine them with your statement:

**[`std::map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) and [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) keep all iterators of the map valid** only if they are executed sequentially.

If they are executed in parallel, one thread (when it starts its work) may face a partially modified object (the other thread is working on it). The result of action on a partially modified object is undefined. This is the source of the problem.

If you synchronize access to your object with say `mutex` everything will work fine. Containers do not have built in synchronization because this would significantly slow down their work while this is needed only sometimes.